# Why does installing Wine uninstall other packages?

Tags: apt, wine

I'm trying to install Wine on Ubuntu 20.04. However, when I try to do that using `apt` on the command-line, it says that it will remove Apache2, Blender, and a couple of other things. Any idea why?

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apache2-data apache2-utils blender-data libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libblosc1 libdcmtk14 libglew2.1 libjemalloc2 libopenimageio2.1 libopenvdb6.2
  libosdcpu3.4.0 libosdgpu3.4.0 libspnav0 libsquish0 php7.2-readline
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fonts-wine libcapi20-3 libfaudio0 libosmesa6 libstb0 libvkd3d1 libwine wine
Suggested packages:
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad q4wine winbind winetricks playonlinux wine-binfmt dosbox wine64-preloader
Recommended packages:
  wine32
The following packages will be REMOVED
  apache2 apache2-bin blender libapache2-mod-php7.2 php-fpm php-gd php7.2 php7.2-cli php7.2-fpm php7.3 php7.3-fpm php7.3-gd php7.4-fpm php7.4-gd silversearcher-ag
  whois
The following NEW packages will be installed
  fonts-wine libcapi20-3 libfaudio0 libosmesa6 libstb0 libvkd3d1 libwine wine wine64
0 to upgrade, 9 to newly install, 16 to remove and 4 not to upgrade.
Need to get 28.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 122 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I'll also add for completion that these are not unneeded dependencies marked for removal, as this command shows:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
# ...
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 4 not to upgrade.
```

**Edit:** Thanks to the hints of Brian Turek, I tried installing it using aptitude:

```
$ sudo apt install aptitude
# ...
$ sudo aptitude install wine64
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-wine{a} glib-networking:i386{a} gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386{a} gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386{a} gstreamer1.0-x:i386{a} i965-va-driver:i386{a} 
  intel-media-va-driver:i386{a} libaa1:i386{a} libaom0:i386{a} libasn1-8-heimdal:i386{a} libasound2:i386{a} libasound2-plugins:i386{a} libasyncns0:i386{a} 
  libavahi-client3:i386{a} libavahi-common-data:i386{a} libavahi-common3:i386{a} libavc1394-0:i386{a} libavcodec58:i386{a} libavutil56:i386{a} libblkid1:i386{a} 
  libbrotli1:i386{a} libbz2-1.0:i386{a} libcaca0:i386{a} libcairo-gobject2:i386{a} libcairo2:i386{a} libcap2:i386{a} libcapi20-3{a} libcapi20-3:i386{a} 
  libcdparanoia0:i386{a} libcodec2-0.9:i386{a} libcom-err2:i386{a} libcups2:i386{a} libcurl3-gnutls:i386{a} libdatrie1:i386{a} libdb5.3:i386{a} 
  libdbus-1-3:i386{a} libdv4:i386{a} libexif12:i386{a} libfaudio0{a} libfaudio0:i386{a} libflac8:i386{a} libfontconfig1:i386{a} libfreetype6:i386{a} 
  libfribidi0:i386{a} libgcrypt20:i386{a} libgd3:i386{ab} libgdbm-compat4:i386{a} libgdbm6:i386{a} libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386{a} libglib2.0-0:i386{a} 
  libglu1-mesa:i386{a} libgmp10:i386{a} libgnutls30:i386{a} libgomp1:i386{a} libgpg-error0:i386{a} libgphoto2-6:i386{a} libgphoto2-port12:i386{a} libgpm2:i386{a} 
  libgraphite2-3:i386{a} libgsm1:i386{a} libgssapi-krb5-2:i386{a} libgssapi3-heimdal:i386{a} libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386{a} 
  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:i386{a} libgstreamer1.0-0:i386{a} libgudev-1.0-0:i386{a} libharfbuzz0b:i386{a} libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386{a} libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386{a} libhogweed5:i386{a} libhx509-5-heimdal:i386{a} libicu66:i386{a} libidn2-0:i386{ab} 
  libiec61883-0:i386{a} libieee1284-3:i386{a} libigdgmm11:i386{a} libjack-jackd2-0:i386{a} libjbig0:i386{a} libjpeg-turbo8:i386{a} libjpeg8:i386{a} 
  libk5crypto3:i386{a} libkeyutils1:i386{a} libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386{a} libkrb5-3:i386{a} libkrb5support0:i386{a} liblcms2-2:i386{a} libldap-2.4-2:i386{a} 
  libltdl7:i386{a} liblz4-1:i386{a} liblzma5:i386{a} libmount1:i386{a} libmp3lame0:i386{a} libmpg123-0:i386{a} libmysqlclient21:i386{a} libncurses6:i386{a} 
  libncursesw6:i386{a} libnettle7:i386{a} libnghttp2-14:i386{a} libnuma1:i386{a} libodbc1:i386{a} libogg0:i386{a} libopenal1:i386{a} libopenjp2-7:i386{a} 
  libopus0:i386{a} liborc-0.4-0:i386{a} libosmesa6{a} libosmesa6:i386{a} libp11-kit0:i386{a} libpango-1.0-0:i386{a} libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386{a} 
  libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386{a} libpcap0.8:i386{a} libpci3:i386{a} libpcre2-8-0:i386{ab} libpcre3:i386{ab} libperl5.30:i386{a} libpixman-1-0:i386{a} 
  libpng16-16:i386{a} libproxy1v5:i386{a} libpsl5:i386{a} libpulse0:i386{a} libraw1394-11:i386{a} libroken18-heimdal:i386{a} librsvg2-2:i386{a} 
  librsvg2-common:i386{a} librtmp1:i386{a} libsamplerate0:i386{a} libsane:i386{a} libsasl2-2:i386{a} libsasl2-modules:i386{a} libsasl2-modules-db:i386{a} 
  libsdl2-2.0-0:i386{a} libselinux1:i386{a} libshine3:i386{a} libshout3:i386{a} libslang2:i386{a} libsnappy1v5:i386{a} libsndfile1:i386{a} libsndio7.0:i386{a} 
  libsnmp35:i386{a} libsoup2.4-1:i386{a} libsoxr0:i386{a} libspeex1:i386{a} libsqlite3-0:i386{a} libssh-4:i386{a} libssl1.1:i386{a} libstb0{a} libstb0:i386{a} 
  libswresample3:i386{a} libsystemd0:i386{a} libtag1v5:i386{a} libtag1v5-vanilla:i386{a} libtasn1-6:i386{a} libthai0:i386{a} libtheora0:i386{a} libtiff5:i386{a} 
  libtwolame0:i386{a} libudev1:i386{a} libunistring2:i386{a} libusb-1.0-0:i386{a} libuuid1:i386{a} libv4l-0:i386{a} libv4lconvert0:i386{a} libva-drm2:i386{a} 
  libva-x11-2:i386{a} libva2:i386{a} libvdpau1:i386{a} libvisual-0.4-0:i386{a} libvkd3d1{a} libvkd3d1:i386{a} libvorbis0a:i386{a} libvorbisenc2:i386{a} 
  libvpx6:i386{a} libwavpack1:i386{a} libwayland-cursor0:i386{a} libwayland-egl1:i386{a} libwebp6:i386{a} libwebpmux3:i386{a} libwind0-heimdal:i386{a} libwine{a} 
  libwine:i386{a} libwrap0:i386{a} libx264-155:i386{a} libx265-179:i386{a} libxcb-render0:i386{a} libxcb-shm0:i386{a} libxcb-xfixes0:i386{a} 
  libxcomposite1:i386{a} libxcursor1:i386{a} libxi6:i386{a} libxinerama1:i386{a} libxkbcommon0:i386{a} libxml2:i386{a} libxpm4:i386{a} libxrandr2:i386{a} 
  libxrender1:i386{a} libxslt1.1:i386{a} libxss1:i386{a} libxv1:i386{a} libxvidcore4:i386{a} libzvbi0:i386{a} mesa-va-drivers:i386{a} mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386{a} 
  ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386{a} va-driver-all:i386{a} vdpau-driver-all:i386{a} wine{a} wine32:i386{a} wine64 
0 packages upgraded, 210 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 129 MB of archives. After unpacking 806 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgd3 : Breaks: libgd3:i386 (!= 2.2.5-5.2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 2.2.5-5.2ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libgd3:i386 : Breaks: libgd3 (!= 2.2.5-5.2ubuntu2) but 2.2.5-5.2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is installed
 libpcre3 : Breaks: libpcre3:i386 (!= 2:8.43-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 2:8.39-12build1 is to be installed
 libpcre3:i386 : Breaks: libpcre3 (!= 2:8.39-12build1) but 2:8.43-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is installed
 libpcre2-8-0 : Breaks: libpcre2-8-0:i386 (!= 10.34-7+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 10.34-7 is to be installed
 libpcre2-8-0:i386 : Breaks: libpcre2-8-0 (!= 10.34-7) but 10.34-7+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is installed
 libidn2-0 : Breaks: libidn2-0:i386 (!= 2.3.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 2.2.0-2 is to be installed
 libidn2-0:i386 : Breaks: libidn2-0 (!= 2.2.0-2) but 2.3.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:                          
1)      glib-networking:i386 [Not Installed]                                         
2)      gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 [Not Installed]                               
3)      gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 [Not Installed]                               
4)      gstreamer1.0-x:i386 [Not Installed]                                          
5)      libavcodec58:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
6)      libcairo-gobject2:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
7)      libcups2:i386 [Not Installed]                                                
8)      libcurl3-gnutls:i386 [Not Installed]                                         
9)      libfaudio0:i386 [Not Installed]                                              
10)     libgd3:i386 [Not Installed]                                                  
11)     libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                      
12)     libglib2.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
13)     libgnutls30:i386 [Not Installed]                                             
14)     libgphoto2-6:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
15)     libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                          
16)     libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                          
17)     libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
18)     libgudev-1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                          
19)     libharfbuzz0b:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
20)     libidn2-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                               
21)     libldap-2.4-2:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
22)     libmount1:i386 [Not Installed]                                               
23)     libpango-1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                          
24)     libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                     
25)     libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
26)     libpcre2-8-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
27)     libpcre3:i386 [Not Installed]                                                
28)     libpsl5:i386 [Not Installed]                                                 
29)     librsvg2-2:i386 [Not Installed]                                              
30)     librsvg2-common:i386 [Not Installed]                                         
31)     librtmp1:i386 [Not Installed]                                                
32)     libsane:i386 [Not Installed]                                                 
33)     libselinux1:i386 [Not Installed]                                             
34)     libsoup2.4-1:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
35)     libwine:i386 [Not Installed]                                                 
36)     wine32:i386 [Not Installed]                                                  

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                                   
37)     libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 recommends gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386
38)     wine64 recommends wine32 (= 5.0-3ubuntu1)                                    



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

**Edit2:** As requested, here is the output of the following commands:

```
$ apt-cache policy "libpcre2-8-0:i386"
libpcre2-8-0:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 10.34-7
  Version table:
     10.34-7 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
$ apt-cache policy libpcre2-8-0
libpcre2-8-0:
  Installed: 10.34-7+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 10.34-7+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
 *** 10.34-7+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     10.34-7 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Further information, I don't have any held packages (as shown by `sudo apt-mark showhold`), and I have enabled main, universe, restricted and multiverse.

Comment: Could you post two things: the output of `apt-cache policy "libpcre2-8-0:i386"` and `apt-cache policy libpcre2-8-0`.  My theory is that you used a PPA to install PHP which, in turn, replaced normal Ubuntu packages and that is causing a version conflict with the 32-bit libraries that wine wants.

Comment: @BrianTurek That's a really good theory, deb.sury.org is a third-party repository for PHP and that is probably what I did, although it is so long ago that I've forgotten.

Comment: @BrianTurek Thanks to your help I figured it out. I upvoted your existing answer.

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I tried installing wine with apt today it removed 26 unrelated packages that *were not unused dependencies*. It removed several gnome core programs, several libraries, and several packages I had manually installed. Took half an hour to clean that up... Most of what it removed was packages that shipped with Ubuntu. I sent an email to the Ubuntu devs mailing list, since it was listed as the maintainer contact for `wine64`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that I was experiencing this problem because I had packages installed from a third-party repository [deb.sury.org](https://deb.sury.org/) . Although I can't remember it well now, I think I had installed a more recent version of PHP from that repository months ago, probably before upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Even though that third-party repository was disabled (as shown in the "Software & Updates" GUI tool), some of those packages were still installed, and had higher version numbers than the ones available in the Ubuntu repositories. This meant that they did not get replaced with updates.

Thanks to help from [Brian Turek](https://askubuntu.com/users/1119058/brian-turek), here's what I did to investigate this and to figure it out:

#### After installing `aptitude`, I ran `sudo aptitude install wine64`:

This gave me much more useful error messages, and showed that the problem was that with conflicting dependency requirements with a package named `libpcre3` (and other packages), specifically with the version number  `2:8.43-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`. That `deb.sury.org` part was a clue that this package was not from the Ubuntu repositories but from a third-party repository, deb.sury.org.

### I checked the source of a package using `apt-cache policy libpcre2-8-0`

This showed me this output:

```
$ apt-cache policy libpcre2-8-0
libpcre2-8-0:
  Installed: 10.34-7+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 10.34-7+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
 *** 10.34-7+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     10.34-7 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

This showed that the installed version was the `deb.sury.org` version, and the the version with the highest version number is the `deb.sury.org` version, but there is another version from the Ubuntu repositories (archive.ubuntu.com).

At this point, I decided to remove all packages from that repository and reinstall the Ubuntu repository versions.

#### Remove the third-party repository

If the third-party repository wasn't already removed, I would have removed it using the tool "Software & Updates"

#### List all packages installed from deb.sury.org

I created a list of all packages from that repository by running:

```
apt list --installed | grep sury
```

#### Uninstall or reinstall packages from deb.sury.org

For each package in that list, I try to uninstall that package:

```
sudo apt uninstall PACKAGENAME
```

Or I would reinstall it from the Ubuntu repositories like this. I would find the correct version number from the Ubuntu repositories:

```
$ apt-cache madison libidn2-0
 libidn2-0 |    2.2.0-2 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

And then I would reinstall it using that version number:

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall libidn2-0=2.2.0-2
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libidn2-0
# ...
```

Comment: Lesson learned: don't add third-party repositories that replace packages in the Ubuntu repos!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!  From my Googling, this was the first time anyone with the same problem (even using the same PPA) solved it cleanly.

Answer (score 3):

It's not actually wine that is uninstalling other packages, it's just apt cleaning up unneeded dependencies at the same time.  At some point you probably installed some application that required Apache+PHP and then removed it using `apt remove`.  When the application was installed, it needed some dependencies but they are not automatically removed when it was removed.

You can test this by running `sudo apt autoremove` which should list all the same packages and then remove them.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not the case. If I run `sudo apt autoremove`, it says "0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 4 not to upgrade." I've edited my question to make that clear.

Comment: Hmm, this is weird and [you're not the only one](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2410534).  Can you try running [aptitude in interactive mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154977/why-is-apt-get-trying-to-remove-certain-packages-when-i-install-wine) and see if that offers an explanation?

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question to include the output of aptitude

Answer (score 0):

If your problem comes from the packages from `deb.sury.org` it can also be solved by adding the repository back again. I did that, because I actually want those versions.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

Also see https://deb.sury.org/ and [https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/).